# Convert Joins to Subqueries in SQL (laravel controller )

Tags: sql, laravel

I have more than two tables, while fetching **2,00,000** records from database taking too much time what I am expecting, so I need to convert it to sub queries?

The following code:

```
->join('track_details','track_details.code','=',$esealTable.'.primary_id')
->join('track_history as th','th.track_id','=','track_details.track_id')
->join('locations as l','l.location_id','=','th.src_loc_id')
->join('products','products.product_id','=',$esealTable.'.pid')
->where(['level_id'=>0, 'products.product_type_id'=>8003])
->whereIn('l.location_type_id',[741,744])
->whereIn('th.transition_id',[537,569]);
->get(['primary_id as iot','products.material_code','th.sync_time as datetime'])
->take(200000);
```

Comment: I think 2,00,000 is not too much while you fetch data from query. But it takes time while you process data with custom methods and loops.

Comment: yeah thanks @Sagar Gautam  Actually i have array_map() and array_unique methods while retrieving this data to json.

Comment: So, you have to look for better way to retrieve data at first rather than query optimization

Comment: Ok Thanks @SagarGautam

Comment: By the way when i use order by clause to particular query it will taking too much time, without order by clause, it is faster.

Comment: I don't know too much about that

Answer (score 1):

If you need all these `data` retrieved with `query` in `json`,

Laravel provides `toJson()` function similar to `toArray()` function. See docs [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#converting-to-arrays-or-json). You just need to add `toJson()` at the end of query like this:

```
->join('track_details','track_details.code','=',$esealTable.'.primary_id')
...
...
..
->get(['primary_id as iot','products.material_code','th.sync_time as datetime'])
->take(200000)
->toJson();
```

In this way, you can directly convert fetched data to `json` format.